# C# работа с указателями как с цифрами

Tags: c#

Есть так называемый XOR список. Для его реализации надо сделать XOR указателей.

в C++ это:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
uintptr_t l = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&a) ^ reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&c);
int* intl = reinterpret_cast<int*>(l ^ reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&a));
cout<< *intl;//3
```

А как сделать это в С#? И как заставить GC не удалять мои элементы т.к. ссылок он на них не найдёт.

Comment: На чистом (управляемом) C#, вероятно, никак. Если только использовать unsafe код. [Пример](https://gist.github.com/chklauser/cb140308780fa05bc434)

Comment: [XOR linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5984487/2881286) - но судя по всему накладываются большие ограничения на все